# Mod Security OWASP with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, owasp, mod-security

I have the application in Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat. I'll want use owasp mod security. How can I redirect network traffic that mod security will see it? My app is on localhost and I only show how mod security works with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain few definitions:

- ModSecurity is a configurable WAF engine which uses rules
- OWASP is an organization
- one of the most popular rule set is the "Core Rule Set", a.k.a. CRS

But yes, generally the OWASP Core Rule Set is a popular expression.

You can use CRS easily with ModSecurity. I'm not familiar in Spring Boot neither the Tomcat, but as I know Tomcat can work with Apache (with mod_jdk?). In this setup, Apache is a proxy. Of course, you can load the mod_security2 module too, and then you are able to use the rule set.

Feel free to ask here, or [CRS issue page](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues) - or mailing list.